# How create file input at form, which upload file and write link in database

Tags: file-upload, crud, yii2, multifile-uploader

I'm trying to learn Yii2 by writing my own cms.

I want realize attachment photo for shop items. I don't know right way to do this, but i think it's should be so -

1. On save, files which was selected in multiple file input are uploads to server.
2. Get the url by each photo
3. Write links in database cell by template

   ```
   <div class="itemImgs">
       <img class="0" src="{link}"> <!-- first -->
       <img class="1" src="{link}"> <!-- second -->
       <img class="..." src="{link}"> <!-- ... -->
   </div>
   ```

Please, help me understand, what i must write in model and\or controller, if its right way. Else, please tell me how should to do it.

Thanks.

**UPD**

Action in controller:

```
  public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new ShopItems();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
      return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
      return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'category' => ShopCategories::find()->all()
      ]);
    }
  }
```

Model contain this functions:

```
  public function behaviors() {
    return [
      TimestampBehavior::className(),
    ];
  }

  /** @inheritdoc */
  public static function tableName() {return 'shop_items';}

  /** @inheritdoc */
  public function rules() {
    return [
      [['category_id', 'title', 'desc', 'price', ], 'required'],
      [['category_id', 'price', 'in_stock', 'discount',], 'integer'],
      [['desc', 'options',], 'string'],
      [['photos',], 'file', 'maxFiles' => 10],
      [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 100]
    ];
  }

  /** @inheritdoc */
  public function attributeLabels() {
    return [
      'id' => 'ID',
      'category_id' => 'Категория',
      'title' => 'Название',
      'desc' => 'Описание',
      'price' => 'Цена',
      'discount' => 'Скидка %',
      'in_stock' => 'На складе',
      'photos' => 'Фото',
      'options' => 'Опции',
      'created_at' => 'Дата добавления',
      'updated_at' => 'Последнее редактирование',
    ];
  }
```

And the view _form.php:

```
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <div class="col-lg-6">

      <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => 100]) ?>

      <?= $form->field($model, 'desc')->textarea(['class' => 'ckeditor',]);  ?>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">

      <?= $form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map($category, 'category_id', 'category_name')
      ) ?>

      <?= $form->field($model, 'price')->textInput() ?>

      <?= $form->field($model, 'discount')->textInput() ?>

      <?= $form->field($model, 'in_stock')->textInput() ?>

      <?= $form->field($model, 'photos[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true]) ?>

      <?= $form->field($model, 'options')->textInput() ?>

    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Добавить' : 'Принять изменения', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
      </div>
    </div>

  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: You could try http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See documentation - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html#uploading-multiple-files

In `controller`:

```
if ($model->file && $model->validate()) {
                foreach ($model->file as $file) {
                    $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
                }
            }
```

Input model `Photo`:

```
if ($model->file && $model->validate()) {
                foreach ($model->file as $file) {
                    $path = 'uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
                    $file->saveAs($path);
                    $photo = new Photo();
                    $photo->path = $path; 
                    $photo->save();
                }
            }
```

Photo table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `photo` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `path` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `status` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Get photos use:

```
$photos = Photo::find()->all();
```

In view:

```
<div class="itemImgs">
    <?php foreach ($photos as $k=>$photo) ?>
     <img class="<?= $k ?>" src="<?= $photo->path ?>"/><br/>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

EDIT
Set in controller

```
 if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
     $files = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'file');
     $photosArr = [];
     foreach ($files as $file) {
        $path = 'uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
        $file->saveAs($path);
        $photosArr[] = $path;
     }

     $model->photos = Json::encode($photosArr);// better put json in afterSave
     $model->save(false);// because validate() run before

      return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
```

In field `photos` you get JSON with path for uploaded photos. In view:

```
$arr = Json::decode($model->photos); // better put in afterFind()
foreach ($arr as $path) {
  echo '<img src="'.$path.'">';
}
```

Comment: Everything is clear, but what if I already have the model and controller, I added them to the question, please take a look. Also i have table for items with 'photos' collumn.

Comment: May be use this behavior https://github.com/developeruz/yii-behaviors#thumbbehavior But i don't sure for use for many photos.

Comment: I found [this](http://programming.peixoto.cf/2014/12/27/yii2-behavior-to-upload-and-save-multiple-files/) Make it, change namespace for my case. But when i want create item - yii throw exception `Class 'backend\behaviors\FilesBehavior' not found` why it happening?

Comment: Show `FilesBehavior` class top of file with `namespace`. And path to file `FilesBehavior.php`. You use that `'class' => backend\behaviors\FilesBehavior::className(),`?

Comment: nope, i use `'class' => FilesBehavior::className(),` and `use backend\behaviors\FilesBehavior`, of course in FileBehavior.php i wrote `namespace backend\behaviors`

Comment: oh sorry, i took mistake in filename

Comment: crap, one more exception `PDOStatement::bindValue() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given
Failed to prepare SQL: INSERT INTO `shop_items` (`title`, `desc`, `category_id`, `price`, `discount`, `in_stock`, `photos`, `options`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (:qp0, :qp1, :qp2, :qp3, :qp4, :qp5, :qp6, :qp7, :qp8, :qp9)` i realy dont understand how realize it...((

Comment: i think trouble in my  actionCreate

Comment: Change `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {` to `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {` and in `if` case show `model attributes`.

Comment: " and in `if` case show `model attributes`." what do you mean?

Comment: o wait, i think i'm do create successful, but images is not uploads, and  table cell 'photos' has `[ ]`

Comment: so, i hope i'll can understand what going on. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure, but i think trouble in your actionCreate. `photoArr = []` - so, thats - `[ ]` saving in database without uploading. If rewrite it to `photoArr = ['ABC']` - in database saving `["ABC']`. It happening even if  delete `upoadFile ...` behavior. It is a pity that the author of the article is not an example of the controller. `Y_Y`

Comment: Ok. `If (!empty($photosArr)) { $model->photos = Json::encode($photosArr); }`

Comment: Sorry man, just my inattention... Thanks for the help, trouble is solved! ^^

Comment: Hi, yes) But I don't promise answer quickly.